# Hybrid composite key in rails - using jsonb field and db column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to add a composite primary key to my project but the issue i'm facing is that one of the fields i want to use is in a jsonb field, and the other key is a regular foreign key.

Is it somehow possible for me to set up a hybrid composite key index?

Something like this:

`add_index :users, [:phone_number, :department_id], unique: true`

Where phone_number is stored in a jsonb field

`meta_data: {phone_number: "987654321"}`

Comment: This one belongs in the bad idea bin. 
 https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64270/primary-key-within-json-data-in-postgresql

Comment: @max True. The go-to solution is to take out the field from jsonb and into a regular column. But wanted to know if that's avoidable.